# IBM.Data.DB2.Core throws exception in azure function app

Tags: c#, azure, db2, azure-function-app

I'm using nuget package IBM.Data.DB2.Core version 1.3.0.100 dll to connect DB2 database from Azure functions with AzureFunctionsVersion V2. Application builds successfully.

When I run the application and hit it with Postman I get the exception:

> System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Personal-GetAgencyDownload. AgencyDownload: Could not load file or assembly 'IBM.Data.DB2.Core, Version=1.2.2.201, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7c307b91aa13d208'. Could not find or load a specific file. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131621). System.Private.CoreLib: Could not load file or assembly 'IBM.Data.DB2.Core, Version=1.2.2.201, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7c307b91aa13d208'.

I see the `1.3.0.100` package, there isn't any other package. Why is it looking for `1.1.1.201` in runtime?

Comment: probably it's a binding redirect. https://nickcraver.com/blog/2020/02/11/binding-redirects/

Comment: Any update now? If it helps you, you could accept it as answer.

Answer (score 3):

Know this is a little late, but just in case others have this issue with the latest version of IBM.Data.DB2.Core (version 3.1.0.300 at time of writing) for me it was due to the Azure function platform defaulting to 32bit, and the IBM dll (or one of its dependencies) required 64bit. Changing the platform setting to 64 bit resolved this error.
You can find the setting under configuration > general settings in the azure portal.

Comment: Hi @Sarah, I am using IBM.Data.DB2.Core (version 3.1.0.400) and I am facing the error described in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67520056/cannot-connect-to-db2-ibm-data-db2-core-version-3-1-0-400-on-azure-function. Could you please take a look at this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This could happen if you have the `IBM.DataDB2.dll` file lying around in directories other than the DB2 client install location. This could have happened without your knowledge where Visual Studio copies the necessary dll into the bin directory of the project.

`IBM.Data.DB2.dll` has dependencies on other client libraries in DB2 Client installation. So refer the DLL from the DB2 Client installation location only and do not save a local copy in the application directory.

Go to the reference in the project and set `Copy local` to `false` for DB2 dlls, referencing directly the ones from the DB2 client setup.