# How Can I connect to DB2 (version v11.1.0.1527) with Function apps?

Tags: c#, .net-core, db2, azure-function-app

I'm trying to connect to DB2 with function apps, but I have problems with DB2 dlls.
I receive this error during the debug of my function app, using latest versions of IBM.Data.DB2.Core nuget packages (1.3.0.100) :

{'Unable to load DLL 'db2app64.dll' or one of its dependencies: The specified module could not be found. (0x8007007E)'}

This line generate the exception:

using (DB2Connection conn = new DB2Connection(str))

The specified dll is present in folder, so someone know what should be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This could happen if you have the IBM.DataDB2.dll file lying around in directories other than the DB2 client install location. This could have happened without your knowledge where Visual Studio copies the necessary dll into the bin directory of the project.

Same question or the duplicate of **[IBM.Data.DB2.Core throws exception in azure function app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60458243/ibm-data-db2-core-throws-exception-in-azure-function-app)**

Comment: The question is different, because my error is not for missing IBM.Data.DB2, but for a dll called by this, db2app64.dll.
I don't have a DB2 client on my location, and I think i don't need it, because I should develop my Function app on an app service plan on azure, and I can't install any client on that.

Comment: Sure. My bad. Just checking if you have think of Azure logic app for this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-db2

Comment: Yes, I started from logic app, they simple connect to DB2, but unfortunately are very limited, because I can read only from one table, I can't join more tables and I can't update more than one row for each time

Comment: I have exactly the same issue, did you finally fix it?
I'm using a new version of the Nuget package (not published in Nuget by IBM, version 3.1.0.200, but still, I have the same issue than you). I hope you found how to fix it...